Word for a function whose integral exists but may be infinite
Let $(S, \Lambda, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function.  The word integrable is generally used to mean that $\int |f|\,d\mu < \infty$.  Is there a commonly used word to describe measurable functions $f$ with the property that $\int f\,d\mu$ exists but may be infinite?  (i.e. it is not the case that $\int f^+\,d\mu = \int f^-\,d\mu = \infty$)
For example, Fubini's theorem ensures that if $f : S_1 \times S_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ where $S_1, S_2$ are $\sigma$-finite, then
$$\int_{S_1} \left(\int_{S_2} f(x, y)\,\mu_2(dy)\right) \,\mu_1(dx) = \int_{S_1 \times S_2} f\,d(\mu_1 \times \mu_2)$$
provided that the integral on the right exists (and may be infinite).  I'd like to be able to easily describe functions $f$ which satisfy this condition.

I'm pretty sure what you're saying about Fubini isn't true - you need that $f$ is nonnegative, or that $f$ is integrable. In the case that $f$ is nonnegative the theorem is usually called Tonelli's Theorem.

No, Fubini's theorem holds under the conditions I stated.  You can find a proof here.  (Note that this source uses "integrable" to mean that the integral exists rather than the usual definition.)

That source does exactly what you should do; it chooses a name ("integrable" $-$ whether we like it or not) and defines it within the context of that source once and for all. If you want another name don't ask others to provide it. Use your authority as an author and give your definition

I am asking if there is already a widely used word for this concept.

That is exactly the attitude I am trying to drive out. I just found extended integrable. Acceptable BUT TBH: the paper of an author that throws this term at me without a definition goes right into the bin.

@KurtG. I never said I would use such a term in my writing without defining it.  You're making an unjust assumption that I write poorly, based only on the fact that I wanted to know if a term already exists.  I am well aware of the necessity of defining unfamiliar (or even widely used) terms before using them.

I don't make that assumption. You can be sure that if I make it that I say that directly. The post has been out now for more than 17 hours and I believe we can be sure that there is no widely used term.
